# Regular expression Wild cards at beginning of string

Tags: regex

I have a string '*This is the monday morning madness*', how do i add a wild card to the regular expression at the beginning of a string to match any string that doesn't have '*monday morning*'.

My **regular expression** example: ^(?!monday morning|Monday Morning).*

The **regular expression** works fine when the string is '*monday morning madness*', but doesn't work on '*This is the monday morning madness*'.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the initial `^`. That character means that the regular expression must match the beginning of the string; apparently you don't want that.

Alternatively, add `.*` at the beginning, as it's already there in the end, to include any character and any number thereof in the matched pattern.

Comment: The suggestion doesn't work, it returns the whole string which is incorrect. The regex is not suppose to return anything from the example because **monday morning** is part of the string.